# Visual Studio - How to edit disabled (grayed out) icon in resources?

Tags: visual-studio, icons, trayicon

In Visual Studio, I've added a new icon in resources. However, for **32-bit** icons, all of the tools are disabled (grayed out), and icon customization seems impossible:

[image]

What needs to be done in order to use those tools to edit the icon (because, if you click on **8-bit** icons, they can be edited with those tools).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In below screenshot you'll see 48x48 pixel bitmap in Icon file but with 32bit color pallet. Looks like that Visual Studio Image Editor do not support editing 32bit images. Therefore, toolbar is grayed out.
[image]

What I did, is that I created same dimension image but with 24bit color pallet. Just like in screen shot below:
[image]
You can see that toolbar is active.

I can conclude that Visual studio can support up to 24bit color pallet. 32bit is just readonly for now.

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Turned out that VS just [doesn't have that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/725d4a71-e4f7-4f90-a8f6-4ef8b2b40cd4/icon-editor-for-32-bit-images?forum=vcmfcatl) ability and you have to create icon outside of VS, with 3rd party desktop apps or online (i.e. [1](http://www.xiconeditor.com/) )